# what does watt specify in induction stove

Tags: equipment, electric-stoves, induction

what does watt specify in induction stove?

Does a higher watt induction stove implies that the cooking will be faster?

Is electricity consumption of higher watt induction stove higher?

Comment: Watts indicate the maximum power consumption. Using a higher power can bring things up to temperature sooner, that will make little difference in cooking time. Electrical consumption will be higher, only if you use the higher settings. Just like a car, if you demand higher acceleration millage drops.

Comment: @Optionparty Please post answers as answers.

Comment: WIth heating appliances, essentially ALL of the energy consumed leaves the appliance as heat in some way - so whatever doesn't end up heating the room cooks your food.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Watt specifies the power of the device.
Power is defined as energy per unit time. So watt is how quickly your device consumes energy.

If it is an efficient device it will convert more of consumed electricity into heat. So given two equally efficient devices the higher watt one will produce more heat faster and can therefore cook faster than the less watt one.

And the third part of your question has already been answered above. Yes, higher watt device will consume more electric power.

Comment: I would say higher watt device will consume more electric power if turned on for the same duration as a lower watt one.